# Linux display files with order

Tags: linux, shell, file, find

How to display all files with specific extensions.
For example, I have a1.cpp, b2.cpp, c3.py, d4.py.
How to display cpp only with numbers.

```
1. a1.cpp
2. a2.cpp
```

Comment: Hum... `ls *.cpp` ?

Comment: Yeap, thank. ls *.cpp | nl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to display cpp only with numbers

Use **find** command:

```
find -type f -name "*[0-9].cpp"
```

---

If "*with numbers*" you meant not numbers within filenames, but the incremental numbers of outputted items/files - **find** + **nl** pipeline:

```
find -type f -name "*.cpp" | nl -nln -s'. ' -w1
```

Comment: It display extra chars. Like ./1.cpp ./2.cpp, can you help me to remove the ./

Comment: @KunyuanXiao, those entries are file full paths. `find` allows you to find recursively. If you only interested to list files in one directory on 1st level - you should mention that in your question